# Distortion Filter won't apply in UIImageView ios

Tags: ios

My application is about taking a picture from gallery photos or camera. For exemple if i take a picture from library photos and display it. If i display it . it shows me a bottle. i should move that bottle and apply distoortion of the image picked from gallery only inside the bottle who is an imageview. something like this :http://postimg.org/image/aw6a7g3t3/

Here is my code :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[ButtonPicture setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"save1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
imageChanged = YES;
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

imageviewPicture.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
 imageN= [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; 

im = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:imageN.CGImage];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"bottle1.png"];


[bottle setImage:image];

 }

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
printf("touch began ----------- \n");
im = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:imageN.CGImage];


 }


 -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {

printf("touch moved \n"  );


UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];

startPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];

//////Distortion
imageviewPicture.image = imageN;
//  imageviewPicture.image.
 im = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:imageN.CGImage];
 CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBumpDistortion"];
 // filter.accessibilityActivationPoint = CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
[filter setValue:im forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
 [filter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:startPoint.x  Y:startPoint.y] forKey:@"inputCenter"];
  // [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:150.0] forKey:@"inputAngle"];
 // [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:300.00] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
 // [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.50] forKey:@"inputScale"];

CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef ref = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:result.extent];
UIImage * uiImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:ref];
[self->imageviewPicture setImage:uiImage];
CGImageRelease(ref);
///////////
//we move the bottle
bottle.center = CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);

 }
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 printf("touch end ----------- \n");
 }
```

The problem now that when i touch the bottle to apply the distortion effect to the image. it apply the effect but the image is getting small whenever i move the bottle. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's a lot of code to look at.  Aren't you able to cut it down a little, so that someone can follow it?

Comment: Not sure, but didn't you forget about setting scale?

Comment: @ trojanfoe : I just cut it down . Thanks